# Function cannot use type inference, but I don't understand why

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

So here is my goofy sandbox to play with Applicatives in PureScript

```
module Main where

import Debug.Trace

data Foo a
   = Foo a

instance showFoo :: (Show a) => Show (Foo a) where
  show (Foo a) = "I pity da (Foo " ++ (show a) ++ ")"

instance functorFoo :: Functor Foo where
  (<$>) f (Foo a) = Foo (f a)

instance applyFoo :: Apply Foo where
  (<*>) (Foo a) (Foo b) = Foo (a b)

m :: Number -> Number -> Number -> Number
m x y z = x * y - z

main = trace <<< show $ m <$> Foo 14
                          <*> Foo 2
                          <*> Foo 5
```

The above works fine, but if I remove:

```
m :: Number -> Number -> Number -> Number
```

it does not compile

```
Error at pure.purs line 18, column 1: 
Error in declaration m
No instance found for Prelude.Num u1150
```

However `(+)` and `(-)` are both of type

```
forall a. (Prelude.Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

Why can't `Number` be inferred?

---

The reality is that when learning PureScript and coming from a dynamic language (JavaScript), I run into type errors frequently. Developing skills in diagnosing and understanding these errors is challenging without a grasp of when inference can occur and when it can't. Otherwise I will have to write types every single time in order to feel confident in my code (lameness).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because at the moment the compiler can't infer typeclass constraints, and as you noted the arithmetic operators are all defined in the `Num` typeclass.

The type that would be inferred for `m` (if the compiler could) would be something like:

```
m :: forall a. (Num a) => a -> a -> a -> a
```

On your second point typing top level declarations is considered good style anyway, as it helps to document your code: [see here for a fuller explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626801/why-do-my-top-level-functions-need-signatures-in-haskell).

Comment: Thank you. Is there a place I can look for style?

Comment: @Fresheyeball I don't feel strict style guidelines are necessary in Haskell-like languages. "Use type annotations for all top level expressions" is a pretty solid suggestion though (they're not always necessary, but even if your program compiles without them they still serve as documentation).